# Upgrading to 17.04 issue: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, 17.04

I am not able to upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04

```
$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
        Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (=
2.14.5-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) but 2.16.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies.  
Try using -f.
```

So, then I tried `apt-get -f install`

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:   libcrypto++9v5 linux-headers-4.8.0-44 linux-headers-4.8.0-44-        generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.8.0-44-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-44-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to removeThe following additional packages will be installed:
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
23 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/8,607 kB of archives. 
After this operation, 1,446 kB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
(Reading database ... 261980 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2_2.16.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 (2.16.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) over (2.14.5-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ... dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2 dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2_2.16.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):  subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2 
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
      Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2_2.16.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I try?